# Python 3.5.1: QVariant represents a mapped type and cannot be instantiated

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I'm working with Python 3.5.1 and I'm trying to run this code but I have a problem with QVariant

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items = ['Item_A_001','Item_A_002','Item_B_001','Item_B_002']

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)       
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return QVariant()
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()

        row=index.row()
        if row<len(self.items):
            return QVariant(self.items[row])
        else:
            return QVariant()

class Proxy(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Proxy, self).__init__()
        self.filterActive = False

    def setView(self, view):
        self._view = view

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        if self.filterActive and '_B_' in self.sourceModel().data(self.sourceModel().index(row, 0), Qt.DisplayRole).toPyObject():
        self._view.selectRow(row)
        return True

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        tableModel=Model(self)               

        proxyModel=Proxy()
        proxyModel.setSourceModel(tableModel)

        self.tableview=QTableView(self) 
        self.tableview.setModel(proxyModel)
        self.tableview.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableview.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)

        proxyModel.setView(self.tableview)

        button=QPushButton(self)
        button.setText('Select Items with B')
        button.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableview)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def clicked(self, arg):
        proxyModel=self.tableview.model()
        self.tableview.clearSelection()
        proxyModel.filterActive = True
        proxyModel.invalidateFilter()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Indeed, when I execute this code an error message appears: QVariant Represents a mapped kind and can not be instantiated .
I tried to remove the QVariant and putting None inplace

```
def data(self, index, role):
    if not index.isValid(): return None
    elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
        return None

    row=index.row()
    if row<len(self.items):
        return (self.items[row])
    else:
        return None
```

But a new error message appears: 'str' object has no attribute 'toPyObject'.

Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

As you've found out, by default, `QVariant` does not exist in PyQt4 when used with Python3. Instead, everything is automatically converted to an equivalent python type. So all you need to do is use `None` wherever `QVariant.null` would normally be expected, and avoid attempting to use any `QVariant` methods (such as `toPyObject`, which is obviously redundant anyway).

Comment: I tried to remove toPyObject but when I execute, the code does nothing. Do you have any idea how to replace it?

Comment: @A.Rym. You don't need to replace it with anything. A python string will be returned instead of a `QVariant` (which is what the error message is telling you). If I make the changes suggested in my answer, the code works fine for me. What were you expecting it to do?